# Laravel Form-Submission Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, entity-relationship

In my app, I have many forms. A Form is its own entity, with its own attributes. When a user fills out and submits the form, a submission is created for that form. Thus, a Form has many Submissions and a Submission belongs to one Form. However... as I just mentioned, a Submission is not its own entity, rather it is an abstract parent to many child entities. Here is a diagram:

[image: UMD Diagram]

So, let's say a user filled out a 'Contact Us' Form. Once saved, a ContactUs model is created.

I would like to be able to query all the Submissions for a particular Form. ie. `Form::where('name', 'Contact Us')->first()->submissions;` This query should return a collection of ContactUs models. Likewise, `Form::where('name', 'Submit a Problem')->first()->submissions;` should return a collection of SubmitProblem models. How would I set up my models/relationships to query this?

Currently, I store my form_id in each Submission model. This is not ideal, because it is repetitive and my Submission model should not have to keep up with its Form's id.

**Update:**
Here is an ERD of what I believe my table structure should look like:
[image: ERD]

Based on what I've read on the laravel docs, this looks like a one-to-many polymorphic relationship. However, I cant figure out how to set this relationship up using an intermediate table.

My models:

```php
class Form extends Model
{
    public function submissions()
    {
         return $this->morphMany('submittable');
    }
}

class ContactUs extends Model
{
    public function form()
    {
         return $this->morphTo('submittable');
    }
}

class SubmitProblem extends Model
{
    public function form()
    {
         return $this->morphTo('submittable');
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Comment: @miken32 yes, I've tried that... but I cant figure out how to set up the relationship. This is not a typical one-to-many polymorphic relationship.

Comment: It sounds pretty typical. I'd suggest posting some code, including database tables, relationships, what you attempted, and how it failed.

Comment: I believe I need an intermediate table for the polymorphic relationship.

Comment: @miken32 is right. Once you define the Polymorphic relationship then you can query based on the related type column values directly for different models/entities. Don't see any need for any kind of intermediate table

Comment: If you do need a pivot table, there is [a polymorphic many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Comment: So if I dont need an intermediate table, where would I put the morph columns? A Submission model can only belong to one Form.

Comment: Ah... it looks like I just ran into a class inheritance issue. :X

Answer (score 0):

Form table would have the following structure/columns

```
//forms table
 - id
 - name
 - description
 - submittable_id
 - submittable_type
 - created_at
 - updated_at
```

```php
class Form extends Model
{
    public function submissions()
    {
         return $this->morphTo('submittable');
    }
}

class ContactUs extends Model
{
    public function form()
    {
         return $this->morphOne(Form::class, 'submittable');
    }
}

class SubmitProblem extends Model
{
    public function form()
    {
         return $this->morphOne(Form::class, 'submittable');
    }
}
```

Queries can be

```php
//Get Contact Us related forms
$contactUsForms = Form::with('submittable')
    ->where('submittable_type', 'App\Models\ContactUs')
    ->get();


//Get all SubmitProblem related forms
$submitAProblemForms = Form::with('submittable')
    ->where('submittable_type', 'App\Models\SubmitProblem')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. The Form is its own entity. A Form has many of either ContactUs, SubmitProblem. A ContactUs/SubmitProblem model belongs to ONE Form, not many.

Comment: @amcardwell In that case you can replace morphMany with morphOne and try - let me update the answer Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I'm beginning to think this isnt really possible using Laravel. :/